# What are the benefits of quick weight loss?

Tags: weight, weight-loss, body-weight, fad-diet, benefits

Although slow and steady weight loss is better than quick weight loss, are there any benefits of losing weight fast? This could include penetrating yourself in the gym or possibly going into a fad diet that "supposedly" helps you to lose weight faster.

Comment: Your premise is incorrect based upon a study of weight loss rates

Answer (score 1):

1. Better sleep: Research shows that losing 5 percent of your body weight can help you sleep better and longer throughout the night.
2. Better hormonal balance: When you rid your body of excess fat, your hormones steady and as a result it's easier for you to maintain or even further your weight loss.
3. Improved sex drive: According to experts, weight loss has been linked to boosted testosterone levels and an increased libido, and dropping just 10 pounds is enough to stimulate sex hormones
4. Increased sexual performance: Between the energy boost you get from loosing weight and the uptick in stamina from hours spent at the gym, if you really wanted to go all night, you could. Increased physical fitness has been associated with greater satisfaction in the bedroom, according to Smith.
5. Better mood: Working out releases feel good chemicals called endorphins. Endorphins are responsible for that high you feel post workout. They interact with the receptors in your brain, reducing your perception of pain and deliver a positive feeling in the body similar to that of morphine.

http://www.mensfitness.com/weight-loss/burn-fat-fast/25-surprising-benefits-weight-loss

Comment: These are all benefits of weight loss but there's nothing there about rapid weight loss, which is the question.